# How can I return a Mono<Map<String, Flux<Integer>>> response in Spring Webflux?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So right now, I am returning a response looking like

```
    @GetMapping("/integers")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public Mono<Map<String, Flux<Integer>>> getIntegers() {
        Mono<Map<String, Flux<Integer>>> integers = 
               Mono.just(Map.of("Integers", integerService.getIntegers()));
        return integers;
    }
```

which gives me a response of

```
{"Integers":{"scanAvailable":true,"prefetch":-1}}
```

where I expected it to stream the `Flux<Integer>` part as well, but it didn't. How would I do this in Spring webflux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring WebFlux can only deal with one reactive type and won't deal with nested reactive types (like a `Mono<Flux<Integer>>`). Your controller method can return a `Mono<Something>`, a `Flux<Something>`, a `ResponseEntity<Mono<Something>>`, a `Mono<ResponseEntity<Something>>`, etc - but never nested reactive types.

The strange data you're seeing in the response is Jackson actually trying to serialize a reactive type (so you're looking at the promise for the data, not the data itself).

In this case, you could rewrite your method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/integers")
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public Mono<Map<String, Flux<Integer>>> getIntegers() {
    Flux<Integer> integers = integerService.getIntegers();
    Mono<Map<String, List<Integer>>> result = integers
            // this will buffer and collect all integers in a Mono<List<Integer>>
            .collectList()
            // we can then map that and wrap it into a Map
            .map(list -> Collections.singletonMap("Integers", list));
    return result;
}
```

You can read more about the supported return values in [the Spring WebFlux reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-return-types).

Comment: I see, well I ended up chainging the @Getmapping to produce MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE

because I was not sure, if returning a pure Flux<Integer> would stream the data to the client and not do any sort of buffering. Largely, due to the fact that i am returning a billion heavy objects(integer was just a placeholder for the actual business object)

In your case, could the integers.collectToList() throw a Out of Heap Memory exception if the Flux<Integer> integers has a lot of things it's going to stream

Comment: sorry, edited the comment above. I pressed enter accidentally, before writing everything

Comment: Haha, I'm often hitting that problem with SO comments.
You're right. In this case, streaming values is the right choice - `Flux.collectList` does buffer everything in memory, so this is not the best choice for large collections/objects.

Comment: Hehe, well I've noticed you around a lot of spring webflux related questions on SO, so your hands must be keystroke-happy by now

That makes sense, thanks!

Comment: very useful for me thanks